# After I reinsert the Webcam's usb the system needs minutes to recognize the device

Tags: usb

I'm using the "Generalplus Technology Inc." plug&play Usb "Joyaccess" branded webcam.

After I finish to use it, I need to unplug it. After I re-plugin it, the system recognizes it immediately with `lsusb` but it isn't ready to use: google meet and other software say that there is no device recognized or the device is loading/initializing. I need to wait some **minutes** before it come back recognized (without re-plug it).

It seems that after I unplug it, the system needs some times to recognize/use it.

How to solve this problem?

I need to use it immediately every time I plug it in.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I cannot upgrade it for work reasons, so **please** don't say that I cannot receive your support because is an EOL version...

Thanks

Comment: 18.04 is eol in 2028,hope you get an answer before that.